# Can HBox "hgrow" be handled via CSS?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a bunch of buttons within an HBox and would like all of them to have hgrow set to always. Currently, I am setting the max width of these buttons to infinity via CSS, and adding hgrow to each button in fxml via HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"

Is there a way to handle the hgrow in css? If not, is there another way to achieve the same effect via css?

Comment: Or you can use FlowPane with Horizontal Orientation.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#hbox), there is no way of controlling the hgrow of a `HBox` via css.